# Can i draw QRect with QPainter and draw something with OpenGL together?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Qt 5.8.0. MinGW 32 bit.
I need to draw objects of different shapes on the screen. I use OpenGL to speed up and draw different shapes, but I also need to draw in QPaint.
I try to draw Rect with Qpainter (drawText function). Text show on screen, but rect not show on screen.

Example

[image]

How do I draw a rectangle with QPainter, not with OpenGL? I want to draw 3 shapes: a triangle and a rectangle using OpenGL, a rectangle using QPainter. My app should to draw any shapes (using QPainter) and sometimes draw particles with OpenGL acceleration. How can I combine this in one widget?

part of DrawingWidget.cpp:

```
void DrawingWidget::paintGL()
{
    m_painter = new QPainter(this);
    m_painter->beginNativePainting();
    m_program->bind();
    m_modelView.setToIdentity();
    m_modelView.translate(-1.5f, 0.0f, -6.0f);
    m_program->setUniformValue("mvpMatrix", m_projection * m_modelView);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vboIds[0]);
    m_program->enableAttributeArray(m_posAttr);
    m_program->setAttributeBuffer(m_posAttr, GL_FLOAT, 0, 3);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vboIds[1]);
    m_program->enableAttributeArray(m_colAttr);
    m_program->setAttributeBuffer(m_colAttr, GL_FLOAT, 0, 3);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

    m_modelView.translate(3.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    m_program->setUniformValue("mvpMatrix", m_projection * m_modelView);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vboIds[2]);
    m_program->enableAttributeArray(m_posAttr);
    m_program->setAttributeBuffer(m_posAttr, GL_FLOAT, 0, 3);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vboIds[3]);
    m_program->enableAttributeArray(m_colAttr);
    m_program->setAttributeBuffer(m_colAttr, GL_FLOAT, 0, 3);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
    m_program->release();
    m_painter->endNativePainting();
    drawText();
    m_painter->end();
}

void DrawingWidget::drawText()
{
    m_painter->setPen(QColor(Qt::green));
    m_painter->setBrush(QBrush(QColor(Qt::red)));
    m_painter->drawRect(QRect(QPoint(10, 10), QPoint(50, 44)));
    m_painter->drawText(0, 40, QString("TEST"));
}
```

main:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QSurfaceFormat format;
    format.setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::OpenGLContextProfile::CompatibilityProfile);

    DrawingWidget GLWidget;
    GLWidget.setFormat(format);
    GLWidget.resize(800, 600);
    GLWidget.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

18.04.17

ahaha, so, when i will draw to rect after draw text app is working, but not working if i try draw text after rect or try draw rect without text

```
m_painter->setPen(QColor(Qt::green));
m_painter->setBrush(QBrush(QColor(Qt::red)));
m_painter->drawText(0, 40, QString("TEST"));

for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {

    int x = rand() % this->width();
    int y = rand() % this->height();
    m_painter->drawRect(QRect(QPoint(x, y), QPoint(x + 15, y + 15)));
}
```

[image]

Comment: You're posting the question with 'OpenGL' tag and OpenGL code,yet you are actually asking Qt SDK related question.Be more specific.

Comment: @MichaelIvanov, thanks for edit.

Comment: Mixing Qt and OpenGl to draw stuff on the same canvas looks like bad design to me. I would rather draw everything using OpenGL (plus it will be faster in terms of performances).

Comment: @neodelphi Oh sure. But the time to insert only one procedure will be less than changing a lot of application code. And i dont know what to do. I think, however, to remake some of the application to OpenGL But now i want to fix this problem or find resolve:)